# Combinining shiro:hasPermission tags

Tags: java, jsp, el, shiro

I am using the tag

```
<shiro:hasPermission name="content:view">
```

in various places in my JSPs to show or hide content depending on the permissions the current user has.

However, sometimes I need to combine permissions, for instance

```
<shiro:hasPermission name="content:view OR content:edit">
```

or

```
<shiro:hasPermission name="content:view AND content:edit">
```

How could I do this ? Can I use hasPermission in 
    <c:if>
tags ? Does shiro has something available for this or should I implement my own EL functions ?

TIA,

Serafeim

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use

```
<shiro:hasAnyPermission name="perm1,perm2">
```

List of permissions must be separated with ","

Comment: Lol probably this for a newer version of Shiro since the one I used before 1.5 years when I asked the question :)

Comment: was this a dream with "hasAnyPermission" ? Last time i checked, there wasnt a tag like this.

Answer (score 2):

Unzip the shiro plugin and take a look at the taglib. If there isn't already a way to specify a list of permissions, you can easily extend the taglib.

The taglib will also show you the code behind the hasPermission tag. You can use this code in if-tags.

Comment: Thanks for the answer - I just wanted to avoid implementing my own taglibs :|